# Do I need to free a JSONArray or TJSONObject even if it is added to another TJSONObject?

Tags: json, delphi, delphi-10.3-rio

Do I need to free a JSONArray or TJSONObject even if it is added to another TJSONObject ?

Code example:

```
var DocHead: TJSONObject;
    DocLines: TJSONArray;
...
While not Dataset1.EOF DO
Begin
  DocLines := TJSONArray.Create();
  //Code that Fills the DocLines array
  DocHead.AddPair('DocumentLines',DocLines);
  Dataset1.next;
End;
...
```

I use Delphi 10.3.3 RIO
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please use code accurately copied from your source.  `Wile not` will not even compile ...

Comment: @MartynA My theory: people code at work, but browse SO from their own device - that's why they re-type instead of digitally forwarding content. And likewise they make mistakes when re-typing code from answers.

Comment: @AmigoJack:  Maybe, but on average, code in qs seems more accurate than that (largely, I imagine, because the OP *did* compile it before posting).

Answer (score 8):

Whether or not you need to free `JSONArray` or `JSONObject` depends on its `Owned` property, which is set to `True` by default when you construct the instance. If you don't change that value, then you don't need to free object that is added to another JSON object.

However, if you don't add the object to another JSON object then you still need to manually free instance you have created.

Comment: So, the code is: DocHead.Free in the example. Correct? I'm looking for working examples because of an AV in my code in similar situation I'm trying to investigate

Comment: @GiorgioCalzolato When you no longer need `DocHead then you have to call `DocHead.Free` .